# How do I save a cookie to a file in Metro?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5

Basically, I need to know how to write this code in .net 4.5.  I'm having trouble finding it in MSDN.

```
private void Savecookie(string filename, CookieContainer rcookie)
{
    Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create);
    BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    bFormatter.Serialize(stream, rcookie);
    stream.Close();
}
```

File has been replaced by storage folder and I can't find a replacement for binaryformatter.  I can't figure out how to serialize the data for the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `MemoryStream` to get the data as an array of bytes, which you can then save to a StorageFile.

```
private byte[] SerializeCookies(CookieContainer rcookie) 
{ 
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter(); 
    bFormatter.Serialize(stream, rcookie); 
    stream.Close(); 
    return stream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the issue is serialization.  BinaryFormatter doesn't exist in the metro runtime.serialization library for some reason, and the xmlserializer doesn't serialize the cookiecontainer object correctly.

Comment: @user1526306 It sure doesn't help that there is no public way to iterate over the cookies in the container.  :(